# Proof of left and right singular vector in SVD

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd

In SVD:
$$M = UDV^T$$
How do you prove that columns of $U$ are eigenvector of $MM^T$ and columns of $V$ are eigenvectors of $M^TM$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $U$: compute
$$
MM^T = (UDV^T)(UDV^T)^T = UD^2U^T
$$
Which is to say that $U$ diagonalizes $MM^T$.  If that doesn't convince you, rewrite this as
$$
(MM^T)U = UD^2
$$
which is to say that
$$
(MM^T)\pmatrix{u_1 & \cdots & u_n} = \pmatrix{u_1&\cdots & u_n} \pmatrix{\sigma_1^2 \\ & \ddots \\ && \sigma_n^2}
$$
The columns of the matrix on the left are $MM^T u_i$, but the columns of the matrix on the right are $\sigma_i^2 u_i$.  The conclusion follows.